# Overriding jquery date validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have started giving support to a very old web application (PHP + mySQL + jQuery). This application has plenty of forms, and in them, a lot of fields to input dates, being the date format dd/mm/yyyy.

All of these date fields are validated with JQuery Validate. BUT for what I have seen this far, date validation may have never worked properly, since all date inputs are validated with the Date validator, wich doesn't support dd/mm/yyyy. I did some research and found out that those fields should be validated as dateITA instead.

For a number of reasons, I would like to avoid to change all the ocurrences of a date element to make them be dateITA elements, so I'm trying to override the date validating method to return the result of validating the element as a dateITA instead.

I'm not very good at javascript/jQuery, and I don't even know if what I'm trying can be done. I thought it would be as easy as doing something as

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return $.validator.methods.dateITA( value, element ) ;

    }
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to debug the returned value, this is the message I get:

TypeError: this.optional is not a function(…)

I have tried a few variations of the code above, but still no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Was looking for a solution for a similar issue , looks like nobody could answer